# Code does not go in to For Loop or Do while loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, debugging

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If Val(TextBox5.Text) = 0 Then
        TextBox5.Text = 0
    End If

    TextBox5.Text = TextBox5.Text + 1
    Dim percent As Double
    percent = (TextBox3.Text) / 100      
    Dim value As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim flag As Integer = 0
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Do While count < value
        Dim rnd = New Random()
        Dim nextValue = rnd.Next(100) / 100
        If nextValue < percent Then
            flag = flag + 1
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Loop
    TextBox6.Text = value - flag
End Sub
```

If I debug step by step the control goes in to the loop my code was working fine.
But when I execute it directly the control wont go in to loop

Comment: Put a breakpoint within the loop and press F5 to confirm the execution hits the loop.

Comment: Yes if a break point is present , execution hits the loop. But once I remove the break point it does not hit the loop.

Comment: That means it works fine  in execution time. Might be some logic issue which is not resolving the result as you've expected. Check your logic and its very naive

Comment: Would you please explain why you believe the loop is not executed? I think you have a different issue here. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the values of `TextBox1`, `TextBox3` and also the output you get in `Textbox6`, when I test your code above it works as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Dim value As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)

Please make sure TextBox1 is having an non-zero integral value.

Answer (score 0):

The following will produce a far better result:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If Val(TextBox5.Text) = 0 Then
        TextBox5.Text = 0
    End If

    TextBox5.Text += 1
    Dim percent As Double = (TextBox3.Text) / 100  
    Dim value As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim flag As Integer = 0
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim rnd = New Random() 'Move this out of the loop
    Do While count < value
        Dim nextValue = rnd.Next(100) / 100
        If nextValue < percent Then
            flag += 1
        End If
        count += 1
    Loop
    TextBox6.Text = value - flag
End Sub
```

Moving the `Dim rnd` out of the loop stops the code creating a new random object every time the loop executes, this means you get a better result as with your code it is quite common to get either `TextBox6.Text` = `value` OR `TextBox6.Text` = 0

Also using `object.Value += 1` rather than `object.Value = object.Value + 1` is tidier and can in large loops improve the speed of execution.